# Multiple statements in ask

Tags: netlogo

Is is allowed to use multiple statements in an ask command. I ask this because my agents do not count their lost variable in a correct way. Slider-s is zero and slider is 10.

```
[ ask smaller [ set heading [ heading ] of larger forward 0.05 set lost lost + 1 set lostcount lostcount + 1 set color [color] of larger
    if random 100 < slider-s [ if lost > random 100 [ set heading random 360 set lost 0 set color random-float 100]]]]
[ if random 100 < slider
[ ask larger [ set heading [ heading ] of smaller forward 0.05 set lost lost + 1 set lostcount lostcount + 1 set color [color] of smaller
    if random 100 < slider-s [ if lost > random 100 [ set heading random 360 set lost 0 set color random-float 100]]]]]
```

Comment: try inspecting one of the agents and printing out messages like `print "got to here"` to isolate the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, it is valid to have multiple commands within an ask block. It is also valid to have multiple statements on a single row (though somewhat unreadable). If it wasn't valid, the green tick syntax checker would throw a yellow highlighted error message.

```
<whatever is the line before - presumably ask some agentset>
  [ ask smaller
    [ set heading [ heading ] of larger
      forward 0.05
      set lost lost + 1
      set lostcount lostcount + 1
      set color [color] of larger
      if random 100 < slider-s
      [ if lost > random 100
        [ set heading random 360
          set lost 0
          set color random-float 100
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
  [ if random 100 < slider
    ...
  ]
]
```

If you use indenting as above, your code takes more lines but it is easier to pick up some types of errors. In particular, is it possible that your code is miscounting the lost variable because the bracketing is incorrect and some agents are passing through these nested loops an incorrect number of times?

Comment: It is the lost count variable that seems strange. Is there something wrong with the slider-s argument? It is an argument that only works when i activate it above 0.

Comment: Please clarify. Are you saying that your problem is that the count does not increase unless the slider is set above 0? Why would you expect it to? If the slider is 0 then the random number is never going to be lower

Comment: Thank you for this answer. Do you see a wrong bracketing?

Comment: Please see my previous comment. If slider-s is 0, then `if random 100 < slider-s` will NEVER be true so why do you expect something to happen?

Comment: Please ask a separate question. StackOverflow is for future reference as well. This question was about multiple statements.